# Zoho API: Get the user that is making the request

Tags: zoho

I have seen Zoho APIs give us the option to get all kinds of user information, yet I cannot find any method to fetch info about the user that is currently making the request.

OAuth2 secured API's usually offer such an endpoint, like [Google](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo) or [Twitter](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json) do.

In their [documentation](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#Users-APIs) there is something that looks like it:

https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/users?type=**CurrentUser**

But then they shatter any hope with their explanation:
**CurrentUser** - To get the list of current CRM users

Is there any known way achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right endpoint: https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/user/info

It requires the aaaserver.profile.READ scope.

Example Response:

```
{
    "ZUID": 123123123123, 
    "First_Name": "Example", 
    "Last_Name": "Name", 
    "Display_Name": "Example Name", 
    "Email": "example@email.com"
}
```

Comment: This endpoint shows up in [this example](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/using-oauth-2.html). As noted [in this community idea](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/oauth2-api-better-document-oauth-user-info), it's not well documented.

Comment: Note that it requires you to include the 'aaaserver.profile.READ' scope (otherwise you will see the INVALID_OAUTHSCOPE error).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this personally and can confirm that the text on their docs is wrong.

They say:

> CurrentUser - To get the list of current CRM users

But in reality, that endpoint really does return a single user everytime, the user to whom the oauth token belongs. So it's not returning "a list of current CRM users", but rather "the currently logged in user" - exactly as you desire.

So your gut was right, and that endpoint will achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: By now I have found a much better solution: https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/user/info

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to me! Can I ask where/how you found it?

Comment: I see that endpoint is listed as an example [here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/using-oauth-2.html) in their mail api docs. As noted in [this community idea](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/oauth2-api-better-document-oauth-user-info) it's not well documented and seems to appear only in that example. Great find!