# Zoho CRM API v2- Current user API (users?type=CurrentUser) returns 403

Tags: zoho

We are using Zohocrm api v2 for getting currently logged in user. It works fine for most of the logins.

But we are getting 403 for one of the user account.

```
URL         https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/users?type=CurrentUser
HEADERS     {Authorization=Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.786ecda99xxxx}
```

Response

> {"code":"NO_PERMISSION","details":{"permissions":["Crm_Implied_Api_Access"]},"message":"permission
>   denied","status":"error"}
>
> Response Code 403

Note: From the same zoho team other 2 users were able to login.

Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54449818/1364747

Comment: No it talks about the same end point But the problem is different. As I mentioned earlier, It works for few user logins and not working only for one user. Also other end points also returning the same error. Ex: https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/org

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the steps with which I tried in Postman. It works for me.

If at all any of the steps are different from yours, you could try these steps instead.

Add the client to get client secret
[image]

Generate auth token giving client id and secret (and scopes)
[image]

After this step, oauth permission request page will be shown, asking user to confirm access to Accounts User Profile and CRM users info. Both have to be accepted.

Use the latest generated token in postman
[image]

Execute API GET
[image]

Comment: As I said earlier, It works for me for almost all the logins. One of my customer is unable to use this API with his credentials. It works for my login. I guess some profile permission related to the customer login (Which i couldn't access)

Comment: @Aram, Are you trying to login without redirect_url parameter ?